# How to distinguish inline links from standalone links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

It's pretty common to apply icons to links using attribute selectors, or else to add a class via script. For example:

```
// HTML
<a href="foo.doc">This is an ordinary text link</a>

// CSS

a[href$=".doc"] {
    background: url('bar.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 2em;
}

(etc)
```

This looks fine on standalone links, by which I mean this type of thing:

```
<p>Some paragraphs of text</p>
<p><a href="foo.pdf">Get the full report in a massive pretty PDF</a></p>
<p>More paragraphs</p>
```

But can look horrible on inline links, by which I mean this kind of stuff:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="foo.pdf">consectetur adipiscing</a> elit ... </p>
```

I'd like to be able to selectively apply icons to the first case but not the second.

So is there a way to reliably distinguish between the two (using script I imagine)?

Have tried to STFW but apologies if it's just my terminology fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically to distinguish between the two, you could use jQuery to compare every  anchor to every parent containing an anchor and if they match, apply one style and if not apply another:

html:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="">link inside a paragraph with other text</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>

<p>
<a href="">link alone in a paragraph</a>
</p>
```

css:

```
.standalone {
  background-color: red;
}

.inline {
  background-color: green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent().html().trim();
    var myTag = $(this).wrap('<p/>').parent().html().trim();//wrap in a temp container to get the <a> as well
    $(this).unwrap();

    if(parent === myTag) {
        $(this).addClass('standalone');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('inline');
    }
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y40o11hu/2/

This will do it for every link, but the initial selector can be whatever you'd like, so it can be reduced down to $('a[href$=".doc"]') or whatever.

Comment: Love this a lot. A couple of queries, though: 1. What kind of impact does it have on performance (I know, depends on how many links) ... <ok, sorry, JSFiddle answers the second question>

Comment: In terms of performance, yeah like you said it all depends on how many links fall into the pattern you want to check. I'm not entirely sure how large an impact it would have, but likely not too horrible if we're not talking hundreds of links per page.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify stand-alone anchors by using more specific selectors in your CSS:

```
/* stand-alone anchor tag */
a {
}

/* inline anchor tag */
p a {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add element with icon like this:

```
a::before{
    background: url('bar.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    content:" ";
}
```